# How do you get to show the full name of application in 'Show Applications' and 'Files?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell, appmenu, filename

In the image below, only "input method" has the full name;  other applications' names are shortened with an ellipsis (…). Why is this? Can it be fixed?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

If you need to see the full names, you can try the extension [Applications Overview Tooltip](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1071/applications-overview-tooltip/) (should work from Gnome 3.20, tested and still working on Gnome 3.32.1, the latest Gnome version to this date on Ubuntu 19.04).

Although the names would not be displayed differently as before, you would be able to see the full names by passing your mouse over the icons.

(If someone has a better idea on how to see the full names directly (without the tooltip), I would be interested too though. )

Comment: Nice! But can you mention which GNOME versions are supported?

Comment: sure, I edited the answer

Comment: Thank you for your answer. but still can't manage to show full name but able to manage it giving it a short name by going usr/share/application and editing .desktop file (ex. open 'google-chrome.desktop' and in name remove Google Chrome and just keep Chrome). To edit .desktop file type sudo gedit in terminal.